# как из большого json сделать вывод по строкам в текстовый файл в Python

Tags: python, json, парсер

Имею Json со статистикой nmap по открытым портам в организации. Json такого вида:

```
{
    "nmap": {
        "row": [
            {
                "service": {
                    "_port": "443",
                    "_version": ""
                },
                "_status": "alive",
                "_name": "SRV-PROD-01",
                "_device_type": "",
                "_ip": "192.168.0.58",
                "_mac": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
                "_has_http": "0",
                "_is_http8080": "0",
                "_has_https": "0",
                "_has_ftp": "0",
                "_has_rdp": "0",
                "_sIsDNSScan": "0",
                "_expanded": "0"
            },
            {
                "service": [
                    {
                        "_port": "3389",
                        "_version": "Tunnel is Microsoft SChannel TLS: unknown service"
                    },
                    {
                        "_port": "54299",
                        "_version": "uTorrent utserver web interface"
                    },
                    {
                        "_port": "58000",
                        "_version": ""
                    }
                ],
                "_status": "alive",
                "_name": "SRV-PROD-02",
                "_os_version": "Linux",
                "_ip": "192.168.0.59",
                "_mac": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
                "_has_http": "0",
                "_is_http8080": "0",
                "_has_https": "0",
                "_has_ftp": "0",
                "_has_rdp": "1",
                "_rdp_version": "Tunnel is Microsoft SChannel TLS: unknown service",
                "_sIsDNSScan": "0",
                "_expanded": "0"
            },
```

Можете подсказать парсер JSON на питоне, чтобы вывод был такого формата:

```
IP Port Port Port
IP Port Port Port
IP Port Port Port
```

Comment: очень неожиданно модуль называется json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну это у вас с виду уже готовый словарь питоновский, просто разбираете его:

```
for item in data['nmap']['row']:
    ip = item['_ip']
    if not 'service' in item:
        print(ip)
        continue
    service = item['service']
    if isinstance(service, dict):
        ports = [service['_port']]
    else:
        ports = (f"{port['_port']}" for port in service)
    print(ip, *ports)
```

Вывод:

```
192.168.0.58 443
192.168.0.59 3389 54299 58000
```

Если надо грузить ещё из файла сначала, то через модуль `json`.

Comment: я использовал ваш код, но получаю ошибку KeyError: 'service'. Он не может найти данный ключ. Прикладываю код: https://skr.sh/sGL7R53XqVx

Comment: Ошибка сразу выходит или успевает какую-то информацию напечатать? Если сразу, значит файл не такого формата, как вы показали в вопросе

Comment: PS C:\Users\Max\Desktop\xml> & C:/Users/Max/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/Max/Desktop/xml/parser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Max\Desktop\xml\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    service = item['service']
KeyError: 'service'

Comment: Хорошо, добавьте перед строкой в которой вылетает, код `print(item)` и покажите, что выводит

Comment: PS C:\Users\Max\Desktop\xml> & C:/Users/Max/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/Max/Desktop/xml/parser.py
{'_status': 'unknown', '_ip': '84.53.255.255', '_mac': '00:00:00:00:00:00', '_has_http': '0', '_is_http8080': '0', '_has_https': '0', '_has_ftp': '0', '_has_rdp': '0', '_sIsDNSScan': '0', '_expanded': '0'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Max\Desktop\xml\parser.py", line 13, in <module>
    service = item['service']
KeyError: 'service'

Comment: Хм, то есть бывают записи без портов. Нужно предусмотреть этот случай. Позже сделаю. Хотя вы могли бы и сами

Comment: Я плохо программирую, и очень рассчитываю на вашу помощь

Comment: Переделал код, попробуйте

Comment: код работает, благодарен за помощь

Comment: @CrazyElf не дали человеку почитать и поучиться :(